# 32-bit Build on 64-bit Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yocto, bitbake, wind-river-workbench

I want to build my recipe into 32bit binary on 64bit system, I have Multilib enabled :

`multilib configuration add in local.conf :`

```
MACHINE = "ti-am335x"
require conf/multilib.conf
MULTILIBS = "multilib:lib32"
DEFAULTTUNE_virtclass-multilib-lib32 = "x86"
```

`Infomation:`

```
Build Configuration:
WRLINUX_VERSION      = "10.19.45.22"
WRLINUX_BRANCH       = "LTS"
BB_VERSION           = "1.44.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
DISTRO               = "openwrt"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "1.0"
MACHINE              = "ti-am335x"
DEFAULTTUNE          = "cortexa8thf-neon"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-wrs-linux-musleabi"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa8 neon thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
```

`The potential multilibs are listed in the AVAILTUNES declaration. For qemu86-64 BSP, that value equals the following.`

`bitbake -e mozjpegcjpeg | grep ^AVAILTUNES`
AVAILTUNES=" x86 x86-64 "

I have followed the steps to enable multilib , but it shows this **error** :
Document : https://docs.windriver.com/bundle/Wind_River_Linux_Platform_Developers_Guide_9_1/page/fau1551818735785.html

```
ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
    Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
    Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:

    Toolchain tunings invalid:
Tuning 'x86' has no defined features, and cannot be used.
```

Comment: Do you want your recipe to be build for x86?

Comment: @GauravPathak , yes, I want my recipe to be build for x86.

Comment: Then I think in that case the `TARGET_SYS` should contain `x86_64`

Comment: `MACHINE = "ti-am335x"` You want to run x86 binaries on a TI am335x ARMv7 processor?

Comment: Dear Gaurav Pathak and TrentP
 
I sincerely thank everyone, currently, I am trying another way, then I will come back to this project, please wait for me! , with all respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your

> MACHINE=ti-am335x

is not pointing to a x86 architectur

rebuild your toolchain when using something like

> MACHINE=qemux86

there are also meta-layers for higher intel or amd cpus